# ECHO page1.php textarea values into page2.php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 php files in my folder. In page1.php, there's a textarea, user should enter some values in it. In page2.php, it will grab what is in the textarea and work with its program. But I can't find a command that grabs the value in textarea. Can someone help me?

page1.php:

```
<?
$hello = "hello";
?>
<html>
<input type = "text" name = "user_input">
</input>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?
ob_start();
include 'page1.php';
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $hello;
?>
```

So, is there anyone that can solve this? =/

Comment: where is textarea in page1.php?

Comment: that is one bad question with bad code. in page1 you don't have any textarea, and even if there's one input there's no form to wrap it and set the actiion/method, neither a submit button to actually send it. On page2 you should just have a $_GET['variable_name'] or a $_POST['variable_name'] to retrieve the value. and on top of all: why actually include page1 in page2 (a page with a form and nothing else) when you don't output the buffer/store it's content in a variable?

Comment: @kawashita86 The reason why I don't have action or method to in page1.php is because I can't possibly use it as only for page2.php because I need the same textarea for page3.php and page4.php etc.. =/

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_GET` or `$_POST` in page2.php

page1.php

```
<?
 $hello = "hello"; 
?>
<html>
<form method="get" action="page2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type = "text" name = "user_input">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?
$text=$_GET['user_input'];
ob_start();
include 'page1.php';
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $hello;
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: output buffering is redundant in this case.

Comment: Hi Bhuvan Rikka, your codes work but I can't let my form action to stay as page2.php because this textbox is for many other php. =/ Is there any possible way to help? =/

Comment: @BhuvanRikka <form method="get" action="page2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> The action part, can I not set it as page2.php because the same textbox is needed for other php, example for page3.php and page4.php etc..

Comment: @BhuvanRikka So does that mean that I have to create an empty page for page2.php so that it only contains the input value?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka I'm sorry but the page3.php and page4.php doesn't seem to get the number; not even able to echo $text out. =/

Comment: @bajeanius Well,i'm not sure about that approach. Forget it. Try storing the entered input in a database. Then you can use it anywhere. But that'll increase the complexity. Why don't you keep all your page3.php and page4.php stuff in a single page2.php? Are they really needed? If yes,why?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Because it is supposed to be like a search engine. If all the other pages are save in one, the program will not know where to apply when values are entered in textbox. =/

Comment: @bajeanius Sounds interesting. Sorry but i'm out of ideas. I'd usually prefer a db for such cases but it is counterproductive to use a database for a single text box! Let me suggest you something. Now you know how to transfer form data from one file to another file.You got the answer for your question. Now post your doubt as a new question! Someone will surely help you .

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Well, if that's the case, see me in another new question! Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 1):

You may use either `$_GET['user_input']` or `$_POST['user_input']`.

The difference is, you can see the data in the url (visible to everyone) when using `GET` method and not in the other method.

Also, always use `<input>` elements (which you want to pass to another file) inside a `<form>` and specify `action="file.php"`, to where you want to pass data, and the method, either `method="get"` or `method="post"`, like;

`<form method="get" action="page2.php">`

also specify the method to grab data in the target file also, like;

`$text=$_GET['user_input'];` or `$text=$_POST['user_input'];`

And in your case, you may use;

**Method 1**

```
<?php
 $hello = "hello"; 
?>
<html>
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

*page2.php*

```
<?php
$text=$_GET['user_input'];
echo $text;
?>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?php
 $hello = "hello"; 
?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

*page2.php*

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['user_input'];
echo $text;
?>
```

If you want to share the data over a number of pages, you may do this using **PHP Session** or saving the data in a cookie.

**1. Using Sessions**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['data'] = 1; // store session data
echo "Pageviews = ". $_SESSION['data']; //retrieve data
?>
```

Make sure you add `session_start();` on every page you want to handle session

You can read more about php sessions here [www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/)

**2. Using Cookie**

```
<?php
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
?>
```

and retreive it using

```
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
```

You can read more about php sessions here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

hope this helps...`:)`

Comment: `$text=$_GET['user_input']; or $text=$_GET['user_input'];` same method used

Comment: Hi @blasteralfred , thanks for the reply but is it possible to not let my form to stay as action = page2.php? Because this textbox will have to be shared by other php pages. =/

Comment: OK.. Then you may pass the variable either by storing it in a cookie or in a session. Let me edit the answer. Also you may give my answer an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

basically your page1.php is a page with some form in it with a text area. Now user will have to fill it and submit the form to page2.php. You can't echo it's content like that, because that will be on browser subject to user actions. Use a form and submit the data to page2.php. Like this:

page1.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="t1">
    </textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$textAreaContents = isset($_POST['t1'])?$_POST['t1']:'';
echo "You submitted: ".$textAreaContents;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cannot let the action to be only set as "page2.php" because the textarea is shared by other php, example, page3.php page4.php etc..

Comment: what do you mean by "textarea is shared by other pages" ?

Comment: Meaning I need this same textarea for other pages use. Like if user input a value in, this value should apply to page2.php OR page3.php OR page4.php, so it means I can't only possibly put it as page2.php. =/

Comment: you will have to post the user data to at least some script. post it to page2.php then maybe you can include page3.php and page4.php in it and thus share the data

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i should use sessions for this. that is where they were made for..

example:when user clicks on submit.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
  }
```

that is where every post variable will be put in a session.
and your inputbox will be something like this..

```
<textarea name="message" type="text" value="" rows="0" cols="0" placeholder=""  ><?php if(isset($_SESSION['post'])){echo $_SESSION['post']['message'];}  ?></textarea> 
?>
```

note that you now can use every post variable that you used in your form by echo (example)

```
echo $_SESSION['post']['message']
```

where message is the name of the inputbox. in this case of the textarea

don't forget that at the end when you don't want to use the session anymore use session_destroy(); otherwise you will keep having it in your form. and don't forget session_start(); above every page where you are planning to use sessions ( it must be at 1st line of your document at all times)